# Ionic - Video is not playing in MI phone

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, html5-video, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to make one page with simple offline video in it in ionic.

I have performed code as follows:

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true" title="">
    <ion-content overflow-scroll="true">
        <video preload="metadata" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline" class="videoPlayer">
            <source src="video/vfile.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

It is working fine in other mobiles, but not working in MI phones.

Can you please suggest me what can i do?